# Where should calculations be done in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013

I need to perform some conversion calculations on data I am pulling from an SQL server. It seems like the best place to do it is in the view while I am looping through the collection, but I am not sure if that is best practice or not. Also, I am not sure how to go about doing it in the view. 
I am still relatively new to this and slowly learning, so I am not even sure of the syntax to accomplish what I am trying to do.

As always any and all help is greatly appreciated.

```
   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

    @foreach (var item in Model.OR_OP)
    {
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            @Html.Raw("<div class=\"panel-heading\" role=\"tab\" id=\"heading")@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.NAME)@Html.Raw("\">")
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                @Html.Raw("<a data-toggle=\"collapse\" data-parent=\"#accordion\" href=\"#collapse")@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.NAME)@Html.Raw("\" aria-expanded=\"true\" aria-controls=\"collapse")@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.NAME)@Html.Raw("\">")

                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.NAME)

                -
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.DESCR)

                @Html.Raw("</a>")

            </h4>

            <div>
                <div class="btn-custom-start">Start</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="btn-custom-stop">Stop</div>
            </div>


            @Html.Raw("</div>")
            @Html.Raw("<div id=\"collapse")@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.NAME)@Html.Raw("\" class=\"panel-collapse collapse collapse\" role=\"tabpanel\" aria-labelledby=\"heading")@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.NAME)@Html.Raw("\">")
            <div class="panel-body">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.PWPLACE)
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.PPARTS)
                @Math(item.PTE.Value/60) <------ this is where I would like to do the calculation.
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.PTE)
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.PTR)

            </div>
            @Html.Raw("</div> ")
        </div>

    }

</div>
```

Comment: Views are for rendering HTML, not performing calculations. Also, lose the `@Html.Raw()` around printing HTML.

Comment: A good practice for a view in MVC is providing all needed info to it, so that view only renders the data. This data object is often called ViewModel.

Comment: I tried it without the @Html.Raw(), and it wasn't formatting correctly.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't use such constructions: `@Html.Raw("<div class...`. This is a very bad practice. Use `@:` or `<text>` instead

Comment: Could you give me an example of the correct syntax? Every time I try to not use `@Html.Raw()` my page does not render correctly. I need the data in `item.Name` to be appended to collapse id. I need this _id="collapse5"_ i keep getting this _id="collapse 5_ with out the `@Html.Raw()'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any logic type operations should really be done in the `Controller`. Then the result should be saved to a `View Model` by `Controller`. That `Model` should be used in the `View` so you can display the result of some sort of operation you performed on data. The idea is that the `Controller` changes the `View Model` and if appropriate the `Entity Model`.

The `View Model` in the `Controller` should be set based on your `Entity Model` if you have one. If you are using DDD, then a lot of the `Controller's` logic should sit in the `Domain Models`, the logic which is appropriate to the domain of course, e.g. Calculations.

So looks like you are using Entity Framework. If you read on the page that you linked at the top:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I think your models get generated from the `Q-MakModel.Context.tt` file. Make sure that the `Context` file contains those two properties, because every time EF regenerates the model, it will remove those properties if they are not present in the template. Another thing to consider, I wouldn't use an `Entity Model` in the `UI` `View`. I would use a custom `View Model`

Then in the `Controller` map the `View Model`to the `Entity Model` and do a save. When you load the `View`, because of `MVC` the `Controller` loads first so you map the `Entity Model` to the `View Model` and return that to the view.

This will protect your `Entity` so you don't save garbage in the database.

In the `View Model` I would only put things which are relevant for that `View`.

I have added this into an answer just because it's too long to comment above.

Let me know how you get on, it's definitely EF deleting those 2 properties.

Comment: I have spent the last week trying to get a better understanding of Automapping and best practices of `Entity Models` and `ViewModels`. I think part of my hang up is dealing with the data scheme that I have to work with. Thanks for all your help. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can do calculation in `Model`. I recommend you add a property in your `Model` class something like:

```
public PropertyName
{
    get
    {                
        return @Math(this.PTE.Value/60);
    }
}
```

Comment: So I tried this, but I keep getting an error.

`public Nullable<decimal> PTE { get{ return @Math(this.PTE.Value / 60); } set{} }`
Error says Math is a type but used like variable.

Comment: You don't need to add `@Math()`, You can just do the calculation and return the result. If PTE is a `decimal? / Nullable<decimal>`, then you will need to do `this.PTE.GetValueOrDefault() / 60`

Comment: @Clint Clark - try this instead, `public decimal PropertyName
{
    get
    {                
        return this.PTE.Value / 60;
    }
}`

Comment: @ShaneVanWyk - I have added those properties to my model and it works great, thanks. The problem now is anytime the data models are rebuilt by the compiler I loose any properties I have added. Is there some way around that? FYI I am dealing with a data scheme that I can not change, and is less than well laid out.

Comment: @ClintClark - I's a bit confused to what is happening here sorry. Need more detail. Are you saying that the compiler deletes the code you added. Or is this a persistence problem? Or a display problem in the UI? Remember that you need to add  `@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.PropertyName )` in the `.chtml` file. Please clarify if this is not the problem.

Comment: @ShaneVanWyk - The problem is in the Model, (.cs) not the View, (.cshtml). I added two properties that I need. If I change anything in the DataModel, ie: add a new relationship, it removes the two properties from the Model.

Comment: @ClintClark - `I added two properties`: This tells me you added a `Getter`, `Setter ` or both to a `Model.cs` File. The only way those items would be removed is if there is something wrong with the way you use an `ORM` like `EntityFramework`. Or in the very unlikely event there is a Ghost in your PC messing with your File. Which ORM are you using? Are you able to post your solution on GitHub so we can have a look at it? It will make it easier to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @ShaneVanWyk, here is the link to the solution on gethub. [link](https://github.com/cclark440/ShopScheduler/blob/master/Q-MarkShopScheduler/Models/OR_OP.cs) The two public decimals at the bottom get removed (PTECONV,PTRCONV)